# Get the child value of .getAttribute validity from a webpage in selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, getattribute

I am trying to get a value nested inside validity using selenium.
I need to get the badInput field inside validity. 
 [validity child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WhTB.png)
I have tried the following but I cant get the option after I use the getAttribute shown below:

```
CreateNewAccountPage().password.getAttribute("Validity").
```

I need to get the child value but cannot see an option for this.

Comment: can you try this way `String badinput= getDriver().executeScript("return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], '::before').getPropertyValue('badInput');",your_web_element).toString();`